# Change Collection View Content Inset on Pan Gesture

Tags: ios, swift

I have my pan gesture working correctly and on pan gesture ending, the collection view content inset is correctly set and the collection view resized, however, I am looking for a way to ensure that the content inset changes whilst the side view is being dragged out. i.e. For every move of the pan gesture the content inset and collection view will update in realtime.

```
self.collectionView.contentInset.right -= translation.x

UIView.animateWithDuration(0.6) {
    self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates(nil, completion: nil)
}
```

Any ideas to ensure that the content inset moves with the dragging out of the side view. Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you setting collectionView inets in UiGestureStateEnded ? if you need it in real time you need to handle UIGestureStateChanged

Comment: Setting it in state changed, but it doesn't update as it is dragged, only at the end when the dragging finishes.

Comment: Do you have a working example that I could test out?

Comment: Update : The cells do move to the right, i.e. The inset does seem to be updating, however, I would like the cells to extend in length, it works when making them smaller but not increasing size.

Comment: Your collectionView will have a delegate method func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
}
within this method you can resize your cells and return them accordingly. Note: If this delegate method is not found then your class needs to adopt UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout protocol

Comment: I am using that function, but how do I call it whilst the user is changing (dragging) the pan gesture?

Comment: call this method in UIGestureStateChanged, instead of performBatchUpdates and check

collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()

Comment: The delegate method will only be called on layout changes. Chances are that with peroformBatchUpdates the delegate method is not getting called.

Comment: Will give it a go, thanks!